# commands bound to buttons in my WPF User-control container are not being called

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am creating a personal finance app using WPF and I have designed it so that I have a main view with a toggle dashboard to navigate between views in my content-control panel. In one of my views, I want to allow the the logged-in user to add and delete (and to implement record updating of course) empty records in a datagrid that holds information of the different bank accounts the user has. Each user's login details are stored in a MySQL database in a table called 'users', which is linked to a table that stores bank accounts called 'banking' using the primary key in the 'users' table (UserID). My issue is that the commands in my user-control's viewmodel are not being called after clicking the UI elements they are bound to and I cannot figure out why.

//when the user 'logs' into their account, their details are stored in an instance of the app, which is handled by my 'UserDataService' class. Any user-specific banking records are stored by database on a local MySQL server with this queried structure:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    UserID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(100),
    Currency VARCHAR(10),
    UNIQUE (Username)
);

CREATE TABLE banking (
    AccountID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    AccountName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Balance DECIMAL(18, 2) NOT NULL,
    CardNumber VARCHAR(16),
    CardType VARCHAR(50),
    UserID INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES users (UserID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

//I then Have a 'banking' view which is nested inside my main view and a banking viewmodel class

//The view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProPlanProject.MVVM.View.BankingView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:ProPlanProject.MVVM.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:BankingViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Border>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Width="130"
                        Margin="20">
                <Button Content="Add Account"
                        Style="{StaticResource ModernButtonStyle}"
                        Command="{Binding AddAccountCommand}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                <Button Content="Delete Account"
                        Style="{StaticResource ModernButtonStyle}"
                        Command="{Binding DeleteAccountCommand}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <DataGrid Style="{StaticResource ModernDataGrid}"
                      RowStyle="{StaticResource ModernDataGridRow}" 
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding BankingData}">                     
            </DataGrid>


            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent"></Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

//The viewmodel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using ProPlanProject.Core;
using ProPlanProject.MVVM.Model;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ProPlanProject.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    public class BankingViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private readonly UserDataService userDataService;

        private ObservableCollection<BankingAccount> bankingData = new ObservableCollection<BankingAccount>();
        public ObservableCollection<BankingAccount> BankingData
        {
            get { return bankingData; }
            private set
            {
                bankingData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BankingData));
            }
        }

        public ICommand DeleteAccountCommand { get; }
        public ICommand AddAccountCommand { get; }

        public BankingViewModel()
        {
            userDataService = UserDataService.Instance;

            DeleteAccountCommand = new RelayCommand(param =>
            {
                DeleteAccount(param as BankingAccount);
            });

            AddAccountCommand = new RelayCommand(param =>
            {
                AddAccount();
            });

            LoadAccounts(); // Load accounts when ViewModel is constructed or user logs in
        }

        private void LoadAccounts()
        {
            int userId = userDataService.GetUserData()?.UserID ?? 0;
            if (userId != 0)
            {
                // Fetch all banking accounts with the same UserID
                BankingData.Clear(); // Clear the existing data
                List<BankingAccount> userAccounts = UserDataService.GetBankingAccountsForUser(userId);

                foreach (var account in userAccounts)
                {
                    BankingData.Add(account);
                }
            }
        }

        private void DeleteAccount(BankingAccount account)
        {
            if (account != null)
            {
                string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=proplanproject;Uid=DeanK;Pwd=Acoustic01;";

                using MySqlConnection connection = new(connectionString);
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    string query = "DELETE FROM banking WHERE AccountID = @AccountID";
                    MySqlCommand command = new(query, connection);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountID", account.AccountID);

                    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (rowsAffected > 0)
                    {
                        // Remove the account from the ObservableCollection
                        BankingData.Remove(account);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while deleting the account: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private void AddAccount()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("AddAccount command called"); //Used for testing if the command works
            string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=proplanproject;Uid=DeanK;Pwd=Acoustic01;";

            using MySqlConnection connection = new(connectionString);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                string query = "INSERT INTO banking (AccountName, Balance, CardNumber, CardType, UserID) " +
                               "VALUES (@AccountName, @Balance, @CardNumber, @CardType, @UserID)";

                MySqlCommand command = new(query, connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountName", "New Account");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", 0);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardNumber", "");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardType", "");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userDataService.GetUserData()?.UserID ?? 0); // Use the null conditional operator to handle null user data

                int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    // Refresh the ObservableCollection to include the new account
                    LoadAccounts();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//these are bound together in my application resources in my app.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/SideBar.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/DataGrid.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Button.xaml"/>

            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:LoginViewModel}">
                <view:LoginView/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:MainViewModel}">
                <view:MainView/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SignUpViewModel}">
                <view:SignUpView/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:HomeViewModel}">
                <view:HomeView/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:BankingViewModel}">
                <view:BankingView/>
            </DataTemplate>
                            
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

[This is how my UI at the banking view looks. I expect my buttons to call the commands I have defined in my viewmodel, yet they do nothing. The messagebox I have written for testing does not appear either](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8sEh.png)

EDIT - My interface implementers:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ProPlanProject.Core
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> execute;
        private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return canExecute == null || canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProPlanProject.Core
{
    public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string nName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your RelayCommand class a custom one (i.e. not from a well known package)?  If so, can you show it to us?

Comment: Yes, I wrote my own classes that implement the INotifyChanged and ICommand interfaces. I will edit my post now to show these, thank you

Comment: Alright, I have fixed the issue. It had nothing to do with my code itself. Somehow the posistioning of my UI elements meant they werent physicsally being clicked. I changed the position of my buttons and now the command has been called. Guess this is the struggle of a 'novice' programmer